# File operation not permitted. Access to path '' is denied in savedialog.sDialog.OpenFile()

Tags: c#, excel, silverlight, internet-explorer, windows-8

I am using [excellite](http://excellite.codeplex.com/)  lib to export excel in silverlight 4, it is working find in windows 7 , the problem here is, the same app export excel is not working in windows 8 IE, it throw an error in sDialog.OpenFile(), but it is working fine in windows 8 chrome.

> File operation not permitted. Access to path '' is denied

```
void exportExcel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SaveFileDialog sDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
    sDialog.Filter = "Excel Files(*.xls)|*.xls";
    if (sDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
        Worksheet worksheet = new Worksheet("Friends");
        // write data in worksheet cells
        worksheet.Cells[0, 0] = new Cell("Column1");
        worksheet.Cells[0, 1] = new Cell("Column2");
        worksheet.Cells[0, 2] = new Cell("Column3");
        worksheet.Cells[1, 0] = new Cell("string value");
        worksheet.Cells[1, 1] = new Cell(478574.5, "#,###.00");
        worksheet.Cells[1, 2] = new Cell(4);
        workbook.Worksheets.Add(worksheet);
        using (var stream = sDialog.OpenFile())
        {
            workbook.Save(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

Windows 8 IE has this limitation or i am doing something wrong?

Comment: You are not setting the SaveFileDialog.InitialDirectory property.  You now critically depend on the default working directory, whatever the one might be for the browser you use.  Chrome is pretty naughty about it, picking an install location that isn't protected by UAC.  IE follows the rules.  Use Environment.GetFolderPath to start at a safe starting point, like the user's Documents directory.  The enhanced protected mode features in IE10 might well give you some more grief.

Comment: but in SL 4 there is no `SaveFileDialog.InitialDirectory`

Comment: Then use Environment.CurrentDirectory instead.